# Probability of a combination drawing from multiple distribution

Tags: combinatorics

I want to find a formula for the probability of a combination of $K$ balls. For examples, $K=9$, and I want to find the probability of having $2$ red, $3$ blue, and $4$ white balls. There are three possible type of balls.

$K_1$ balls draw from distribution $1$, $K_2$ balls draw from distribution $2$, and $K_3$ balls draw from distribution $3$. Obviously, $K_1+K_2+K_3 = K$. All draws are with replacement and each distribution has different density. For example, in distribution $1$, the probability of getting a red, blue, and white balls are $p^1_r$, $p^1_b$, $p^1_w$. And so on.

I believe this problem must be solved somewhere but I couldn't find it after a lot of Googling. Your answer will be much appreciated!

Comment: You might be interested in the Multinomial Distriution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution

Comment: Thank you for the link. So the solution to my questions is like combining three different multinomial distribution?

Comment: No, I think you should consider a single multinomial distribution with 3 categories.

Comment: Sorry but I am still not seeing how it works. There are 3 categories but within each categories, the probabilities are different. To use the ball drawing experiment, I am extracting K balls of 3 different colors from 3 bags. I thought the single multinomial distribution would only work for K balls of 3 different colors from 1 bag.

Comment: The multinomial distribution allows for different probabilities for the categories.  It doesn't matter how many bags you have if you draw with replacement.

Comment: Thanks again. I think I have found a similar question but unanswered

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/264070/multinomial-distribution-with-different-probabilities-for-each-trial

In my example, $K_1$ trials have different probabilities from $K_2$ trials. I don't see anywhere in the Wiki page suggesting that there is a formula for it.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at the pmf listed on the wiki.

Comment: I did. When it says "$p_i$ the probability that a given extraction will be in color $i$", in my example, $p_i$ are different in the first $K_1$ trials from the rest of the trials for example. How can I use the formula? Many thanks again

Comment: In that case I do not understand the problem statement.  Perhaps you should edit your problem statement to specify just how the probabilities vary.

Answer (score 1):

Defining $K:=K_1+K_2+K_3$, there are $\frac{K!}{K_1!K_2!K_3!}$ different orders to draw $K_1$ red, $K_2$ blue and $K_3$ white balls. Let the probability in each drawing for "red" be $p_1$, for "blue" be $p_2$ and for "white" be $p_3$, then the probability for $K_1$ red, $K_2$ blue and $K_3$ white balls is:
$$P(K_1, K_2, K_3) = \frac{K!}{K_1!K_2!K_3!}p_1^{K_1}p_2^{K_2}p_3^{K_3}$$